# Элементы управления google maps

Tags: google-maps

Вставляю гугл карту на сайт через `iframe`.

1. Есть ли возможность отключить элементы управления на карте?
2. По бокам карты добавляются ненужные иконки, хотелось бы от них
   избавиться.

Comment: Если при генерации кода вставки `iframe` нет параметров для отключения этих параметров, то убрать их не получится.

Comment: Выводите карту через js https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?hl=ru

Comment: Придется тогда вникать в гугл maps API, спасибо за помощь.